Why I can't run Apache container in Docker (I get Status Exited (1))
I'm trying to setup Apache with Docker to make redirect for url - adress.
My SSL-certificate created with Certbot and working for my url-adress.
Files located in this folder /etc/letsencrypt/archive/my-url-adress.com:
cert1.pem  chain1.pem  fullchain1.pem  privkey1.pem

My Dockerfile in /opt/apache:
FROM httpd:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/apache2/logs


COPY ./httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

My httpd.conf in /opt/apache:
ServerName my-adress.com
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so


Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName my-adress.com

        SSLEngine on

    ErrorLog /usr/local/apache2/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache2/logs/access.log combined


        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/dashboard/list$ /dashboards-list [R=301,L]

        ProxyPass /dashboards-list http://localhost:8088/dashboard/list
        ProxyPassReverse /dashboards-list http://localhost:8088/dashboard/list
</VirtualHost>

Then I run command:
docker build -t my-apache .


docker run -d --name apache -v /etc/letsencrypt/archive/beauty-unity-analytics.ru/fullchain1.pem:/usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl.crt -v /etc/letsencrypt/archive/beauty-unity-analytics.ru/privkey1.pem:/usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl.key -p 443:443 my-apache

docker logs -f apache

As result docker image exists, bun container not running.
Then I use run command I get no errors.
In docker ps -a status for container: Exited(1).
Logs for container is empty.
I checked:
docker logs

And
/var/lib/docker/containers/578e0ca4882ded6d2d170cb2cf8690c1a43580354d2f08ee0ce10525735dc223/578e0ca4882ded6d2d170cb2cf8690c1a43580354d2f08ee0ce10525735dc223-json.log


Do not bundle your TLS keys into a Docker image.  Anyone who gets a copy of the image can trivially docker cp the keys and certificates out, at which point they can impersonate your server.  I'd use a docker run -v option to inject them at run time, at which point you can use the unmodified httpd:alpine image.

Thanks, but I still got error AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.

The

AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.

indicates that your config is not loading the MPM modules....
You may try to add this to your httpd.conf file:
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so


I need add LoadModue before "<VirtualHost *:443>", right?

Bydefault MPM configuration available inside $Httpd_Home/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf file. So Make sure that LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so is uncommented/available inside that file. Also make sure that mod_mpm_event.so is available $Httpd_Home/modules  directory.

I've just updated question, cause I solve some errors, but stuck at "no listening sockets available" error.

Add Listen 443 before VirtualHost.

When I adding Listen 443 container created. But got status Exited(1) and got no logs. =/

Run docker ps -la (to list all containers that exited with error code or failed to start. then check the logs using: docker logs <container_id>.
